# What could be eating or removing the insulation in my garage door?

Tags: doors, garage, pest-control

We have noticed that there are piles of the tiny particles of the insulation from one of our garage doors on each side of our door. At first we swept it up and didn't think anything of it. The next day there were piles again! It just keeps happening. Any idea what might be inside of the door eating the insulation or just moving around inside of it to have it pile up on the floor? So strange.

Comment: At the very least you have to specify the insulation material. Photos of the piles (and other damage if you can see it) could also be helpful.

Comment: The most obvious explanation would probably be mice or rats.

Comment: look for evidence of mouse droppings(small dark pieces similar in size and shape to cupcake sprinkles) along the walls and in the corners.

Comment: Carpenter ants like to tunnel through some insulation types. It's easier for them than wood. :-)

Comment: I had carpenter ants eating the foam ICF blocks below grade I wasent worried about the structure as I had metal flashing that they could not chew through, I ended up having them professionally removed as there must have been thousands a dust pan full every day of the tiny foam pieces. I had 65' of wall below grade up to 11'.  the company used 35 gallons of some really toxic stuff (10 year guarantee) it was expensive but 2 years later there was no more mess. + jay

Answer (score 1):

Carpenter ants, they did the same in my insulated (Styrofoam) garage door. They attacked one door but not the second. I stopped them with Sevin dust but it needed a couple months. I just sprinkled it on the floor where the door touched ( because it is "flea powder" it is very low risk to pets.)